# CakePHP Cache Not Writing File

Tags: caching, cakephp-2.0

I cannot figure this one out ... that means it's got to be an easy one, right?!

Problem: Cake not writing files to file cache.

Configuration:

```
//app/Config/core.php

Configure::write('debug', 0);

Configure::write('Cache.disable', true);

Configure::write('Cache.check', true);

//app/Config/bootstrap.php

Cache::config('default', array('engine' => 'File'));

//app/Controller/CategoriesController.php, 'view' method:

public function view($id = null) {

$this->helpers[] = 'Format';
$this->helpers[] = 'Cache';
$this->cacheAction = "3600";    

....
}
```

Perms on the app/tmp/cache/* are 0777. world writable.

But still not files being written to cache .... what am I missing??

DJC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Configure::write('Cache.disable', true);
```

You don't know why the cache is not being written...?

Comment: Well, so it seems backwards, I know, but according to the cookbook, this line is set to true out of the box, but commented out, and it says to 'uncomment the line' if you want to use the cache, which I've done. If I set this to false, I get a white screen of death, no error message, not even in the logs (even if/when debug mode is changed 1 or 2)

Comment: Yup, your first comment was right. I don't know why I was getting a white screen, but it's gone now. Thanks.